# TestNG runs every method and ignores the included methods from testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I create my testng.xml programatically and I would like to add each method what I want to run. I'm doing it on the following way right now:

```
XmlClass myClass = new XmlClass("test.login.LoginTest");
List<XmlInclude> includedMethods = new ArrayList<XmlInclude>();

for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {

  includedMethods.add(new XmlInclude("golog" + k));
}

myClass.setIncludedMethods(includedMethods);
```

According to my generated testng.xml file, it seems it works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="11" verbose="11" name="Login Test" parallel="tests">
  <test name="1" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.login.LoginTest">
        <methods>
          <include name="golog1"/>
          <include name="golog2"/>
          <include name="golog3"/>
          <include name="golog4"/>
          <include name="golog5"/>
          <include name="golog6"/>
          <include name="golog7"/>
          <include name="golog8"/>
          <include name="golog9"/>
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- test.login.LoginTest -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- 1 -->
</suite> <!-- Login Test -->
```

The problem is that when my code get executed after generating the xml file, every `@Test` method get executed *(those methods too which has completely different name, like "gssig01")* despite the fact that I didn't include them.

My question is that do I have to maybe exclude every methods before including anything, or I did something wrong? :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you actually running the tests? Are you using maven?

Comment: Yes I'm using maven.

Comment: Can you please add the maven setup as well? How are you actually telling maven to run your generated xml instead of executing the default config?

Comment: I'm using the `exec-maven-plugin` from `org.codehaus.mojo` and I added my class (which contain the testng.xml generating) as `mainClass` to the configuration. And it works fine because everything get generated to the xml. So it seems that the problem is not with the XML generate but with the xml reading.

Comment: If the xml file given above is the generated one, yeah it looks like a valid one and it should not include other methods. So when you are running it from maven, you are first generating the xml and then running the test cases from that generated xml or you are creating a testng object and running it by tng.run(); from the runner main method itself ?

Comment: @ChandanNayak: I'm creating a testng object and running it by tng.run().

Comment: Need to check that class, if you can share it.

Comment: @ChandanNayak: There is nothing special in my class. I just create a correct XmlSuite, add it to a TestNG() class, then I run it by tng.run(). As I said, everything is okay with my tests. I set a lot of things in my xml file and everything get setted perfectly. The problem is that when I run my test, it denies my included methods. But everything else works fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code, it works**

```
//Create a list which can contain the classes that you want to run including methods.
 List<XmlClass> myClasses = new ArrayList<XmlClass> ();
 XmlClass xmlclass = new XmlClass("stack1.LoginTest");

 List<XmlInclude> includedMethods = new ArrayList<XmlInclude>();

 for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {

   includedMethods.add(new XmlInclude("golog" + k));
 }
 xmlclass.setIncludedMethods(includedMethods);

 myClasses.add(xmlclass);
```

---

Here is the output where i had 7 methods and only 4 ran

```
golog1test1
golog2test2
golog3test3
golog4test4

===============================================
StackOverFlow-Answer
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

If you want to check the full class:
[RunTestNG.java](https://github.com/Chandan-Nayak/stackoverflow-files/blob/master/RunTestNG.java) - Test runner class
[LoginTest.java](https://github.com/Chandan-Nayak/stackoverflow-files/blob/master/LoginTest.java) - Test class

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. After a day it started work fine for me, so it seems it was a cache problem or something similar. But anyway thank you for your answer and for your help.